# csp_whitelist.xml for themes

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, custom-theme, content-security-policy

Content security policies for **custom modules** can be added by setting up a csp_whitelist.xml file, i.e. `app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/cps_whitelist.xml`, this is more or less excessively described in the [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/security/content-security-policies.html#configure-csps-for-your-custom-codeextensiontheme).

However, the docs also mention

> Configure CSPs for your custom code/extension/**theme**

Yet, I seem to be unable to get a working whitelist addition from within a **custom theme**, i.e. `app/design/Vendorname/Themename/etc/cps_whitelist.xml`?

`etc/csp_whitelist.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="fontsGoogleapisCom" type="host">fonts.googleapis.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

This very same whitelist is working and brings me the expected result when moved to a custom module (i.e. `app/code/Vendorname/ThemenameCsp`).

Am I *supposed* to create a custom-theme-related custom module just to allow my custom theme to load an external font? Seems a bit nasty to me if that's actually the case.

Answer (score 4):

Unless one may come up with a better solution, this is my workaround:

As it looks, we can just extend the theme's registration.php to register as a theme and as module (?!) to something like this:

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/Vendorname/Themename', __DIR__);
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendorname_Themename', __DIR__);
```

Now, once a `etc/module.xml` is in place we also can add a `csp_whitelist.xml` with the very same content as mentioned in the question above.

*Note: As I am not sure whether this is the indented way to go I'll keep the question unanswered for the time being.*

Comment: interesting solution - I like your thinking...